# Jest throw error when I write test using TypeScript syntax

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babeljs, ts-jest, babel-jest

I have error on my test.ts file,

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token

File was processed with these loaders:
./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an aaadditional loader to handle the result of these loaders.

describe('FormDataAccess`, () => {
  test('Something', () => {
    const formData: FormData = {
      ......
    }
    ......
    expect(ABC).toEquaal(A.B?.C);
})
}
```

If I remove the `:FormData` and remove the `?` , it will compile successfully.

This is my Jest Config file:

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.ts'],
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json'],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/', '/src/i18n/__tests__', 'dist/', 'build/'],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
        '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest'
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$', '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$'],
    testMatch: ['**/*.(test|spec).(js|ts|tsx)'],
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '\\.(jpg|ico|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
        '\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$': 'identity-obj-proxy'
    },
    roots: ['<rootDir>', 'src', 'node_modules'],
    modulePaths: ['<rootDir>'],
    clearMocks: true,
    collectCoverage: true,
    collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{ts,tsx}', '!**/*.stories.{ts,tsx}', '!src/index.ts', '!**/node_modules/**'],
    coverageDirectory: './build/brazil-documentation/coverage',
    coverageReporters: ['json-summary', 'text', 'html', 'cobertura']
};
```

This is my WebPack config file's rule:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            // Include ts, tsx, js, and jsx files.
            test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                babelrc: true
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|bmp|svg)$/,
            use: 'url-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        }
    ]
},
```

Babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'
],
presets: ['@babel/preset-typescript', '@babel/preset-env'],
ignore: [/(test).(ts|js)x?$/, /(stories).(ts|js)x?$/]
```

};

Can someone guide me how can I resolve this error, what is a must have in my Jest or webpack config file?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you also share your jest config file?

Comment: It seems you don't have a `ts-loader`.

Comment: I just shared my jest config file

Comment: Adding a seperate ts loader is a bit excessive imho, especially if babel is already installed and babel jest is used. Adding ts support to .babelrc with sth similar to [babel-preset-typescript](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript) might do the trick and will be much simpler. If by any chance you are also using react/nextjs, babel almost surely has a preset/plugins for that as well.

Comment: I usually also setup a seperate .babelrc to keep the test config from interfering with project settings and then linking it directly to `babel-jest` in jest config. [Here](https://github.com/atlasgroupcz/react-wrap/blob/master/jest.config.js) and [here](https://github.com/atlasgroupcz/react-wrap/blob/master/babelrc.tests.json) is a quite a minimalistic example of a react ts component testing setup with `jest` which you might find useful :)

Comment: @XinruiMa Could you also share `babelrc` file?

Comment: @SubratoPattanaik I just did

Comment: https://github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/issues/541 Maybe this will help